# Solr delopyment Server memory Increase

Tags: solr

I follow that link Instruction. Click [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Taking+Solr+to+Production#TakingSolrtoProduction-SeparateDirectoryforWritableFiles)

and then I increase Solr memory in here... /var/solr/solr.in.sh.
Like that SOLR_JAVA_MEM="-Xms3g -Xmx3g". After that, I restart solr but it doesn't change in SOLR AdminUI. Is there any way to increase solr meomry? [image]

Comment: Try to give additional parameter **-m** for memory setting while starting solr  
`$ bin/solr start -m 3g`.

Comment: @sanjayduttindia .. so if I do like that, I have to write everytime, when I restart sever. I would like to do predefined memory.